# Visual Studio and Post-mortem debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, vsjitdebugger

I would like to know how `vsjitdebugger.exe` can cause a particular running instance of Visual Studio to be used to debug a process.

Background: currently `vsjitdebugger.exe` is set as the executable run whenever there is a "debug break" - i.e. in C# `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();`. Whenever this happens I see a dialog with a list of available debuggers - this includes all running instances of Visual Studio.

My question is how `vsjitdebugger.exe` activates a particular **running** instance of Visual Studio. Please note that I am particularly interested in existing running instances of VS and not in starting a new instance.

Comment: Maybe the message is sent through a pipe. Or maybe it's a windows message. Or some COM/ActiveX sort of thing. Or even a TCPIP socket (not very likely though). What does it matter?

Comment: @Dialecticus it matters because I want to replace `vsjitdebugger.exe` (in itself very easy to do) and come up with a non-interactive way of activating the right instance of Visual Studio under certain circumstances.

Comment: Maybe you could use Process Monitor (from SysInternals Suite) to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can attach the process to vs debugger through VS sdk.

```cs
public static void Attach(DTE dte)  
{  
    EnvDTE.Processes processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;  
    foreach(EnvDTE.Process proc in processes)  
        if(proc.Name.IndexOf("Target.exe") != -1)  
            proc.Attach();  
}
```

The document: [Process Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.process?view=visualstudiosdk-2019)